# Proper POST request to stream data to plotly from Arduino

Tags: post, arduino, plotly, esp8266

I'm using an ESP8266 module in order push sensory data online. I set it up for thingspeak and used a simple GET request to send the values.

Now I was trying to replicate the process with plotly data streaming service but I can't figure out what is wrong with my request.

The traditionnal libraries (Wifi, Ethernet etc.) have a println() method which prints to the socket. I had to implement my own library for the ESP since I could not find anything reliable, and noticed that very often the device would put itself in a 'busy' state after sending something to the socket, which prevented me from sending the request chunk by chunk like such :

```cc
client.println("POST / HTTP/1.1")
client.println("Host: arduino.plot.ly")
client.println("{\"x\":15, \"y\": 3, \"streamtoken\": \"urqcbfmjot\"\"}")
```

So I tried to write the request all at once. I found the parameters for the request by diving into plotly's arduino librarie which relies on Wifi to work (which is why I can't use it with the ESP). I have failed to push any data until now. Here is the chunk of code reponsible for sending the request :

```cc
void pushData(String temp, String humid, String pres, String lum)
{
    bool status = esp8266.openTCPConnection(IP, PORT);

    char call[] = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    strcat(call, "Host: arduino.plot.ly\r\n");
    strcat(call, "User-Agent: Arduino\r\n");
    strcat(call, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n");
    strcat(call, "Connection: close\r\n");
    strcat(call, "\r\n");
    strcat(call, "\r\n{\"x\":15, \"y\": 3, \"streamtoken\": \"urqcbfmjot\"\"}\n\r\n");

    if (!status) return;

    esp8266.send(call);
}

void Esp8266::send(String content)
{
    String cmd;
    String msg = "Sent : ";
    bool status;

    printDebug("Writing to TCP connection");
    printDebug("Content to write :");
    printDebug(content);
    cmd = "AT+CIPSEND=" + String(content.length());
    espSerial.println(cmd);
    printDebug("Sent : " + cmd);

    status = checkResponse(">", 10);
    if (status)
    {
        espSerial.print(content);
        printDebug("Content sent");

        } else {
        printDebug("Cursor error");
        closeTCPConnection();
    }

}
```

I might add that I've succesfully tested the request provided in their [documentation](https://plot.ly/streaming/) with cUrl, but it failed too in my implementation. The request is :

```html
POST  HTTP/1.1
Host: stream.plot.ly
plotly-streamtoken: urqcbfmjot

{ "x": 10, "y": 2 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. For references, here is the [repository](https://github.com/amatelin/Connected-barometer-tutorial/tree/plot.ly) of my project.

Feel free to use my graph for testing purposes. The host is either stream.plot.ly (from the doc) or arduino.plot.ly (from the library). My stream token is **urqcbfmjot** and here is [the link to the plot](https://plot.ly/170/~amatelin/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to send your data in [chunked format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Encoded_data).

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: stream.plot.ly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
plotly-streamtoken: urqcbfmjot

14
{ "x": 10, "y": 2 }
```

your HTTP request with single data update should look like:

```cpp
char call[] = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
strcat(call, "Host: stream.plot.ly\r\n");
strcat(call, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n");
strcat(call, "plotly-streamtoken: urqcbfmjot\r\n");
strcat(call, "\r\n");
strcat(call, "11\r\n"); // 11 is the length of the JSON string + "\n" in hexadecimal format
strcat(call, "{\"x\":15, \"y\": 3}\n\r\n");
```

to send another data point, you don't need to make another connection. If you keep the existing stream connection open, you can just send the next chunk

```cpp
esp8266.send("12\r\n{\"x\":30, \"y\": 10}\n\r\n");
```

but acording to the documentation,

> A client stops writing data for a time period longer than a minute. If a minute passes without receiving any data from the client the stream connection will be closed. (A connection can be maintained by writing a heartbeat within the 60 second window, a heartbeat is simply a newline).

the server will close the connection, if you don't send anything in more than one minute. You could send a chunk with just  a new line character `"1\r\n\n\r\n"` if you don't have to send anything in a minute.

But you will probably still need to detect a disconnection, if the connection drops for any other reason and try to reconnect.